# Pip install on Yocto failing

Tags: python, yocto, intel-edison

Testing an Intel Edison board that runs Yocto with Python2.7 preinstalled. 
Having issues installing libraries.
wget version Busybox do not allow https downloads. 
apt-get is not available in Yocto. 
Curl worked for some libraries but not for all.
Finally installed setuptools and pip with get-pip.py using curl but encounter this issue when doing a pip install on any library "setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When I solved it, I wrote this post: http://mendrugory.weebly.com/blog/intel-edison-and-python

Maybe, It could be useful for you.